# Await / async on anonymous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

I'm trying to use await on an anonymous function here are the results :

This is the way that works

```
async function hello(){
    return "hello";
}
let x = await hello();
console.log(x);
```

result :

> > "Hello"

This is the way i want it to work :

```
let x = await async function() {return "hello"};
console.log(x);
```

result :

> > [AsyncFunction]

What am i missing ? I'm new to promises.

**EDIT :** 
I tried adding the () after the anonymous function to call it. Here is the example with the actual Async code :

```
let invitationFound = await (async function (invitationToken, email){
    return models.usersModel.findOneInvitationByToken(invitationToken, email)
        .then(invitationFound => {

            return  invitationFound;
        })
        .catch(err =>{
           console.log(err);
        });
})();

console.log(invitationFound);
return res.status(200).json({"oki " : invitationFound});
```

Result of the console.log :

> > ServerResponse {
> >       domain: null,
> >       _events: { finish: [Function: bound resOnFinish] },
> >       _eventsCount: 1,
> >       _maxListeners: undefined,
> >       output: [],
> >       outputEncodings: [],
> >     .....

Result of the res.code..

> > handledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

I don't think the error come from models.usersModel.findOneInvitationByToken because it works fine when i use it in the first case

```
let userFound = await test(invitationToken, email);
```

**EDIT 2 :**

I found out the second problem ! I forgot to put the parameters into the parenthesis

```
let invitationFound = await (async function (invitationToken, email){
    return models.usersModel.findOneInvitationByToken(invitationToken, email)
        .then(invitationFound => {

            return  invitationFound;
        })
        .catch(err =>{
           console.log(err);
        });
})(invitationToken, email);

console.log(invitationFound);
return res.status(200).json({"oki " : invitationFound});
```

result :

> > {  oki : {mydata} }

Comment: Why are you using async/await on a synchronous function?

Comment: In the second snippet, you're just declaring the function but you don't call it.

Comment: @alfasin how do i call it on the same line ?

Comment: @Couteau see Jacob's answer

Comment: @Li357 it was just for the example, i didnt thought it would be because of the sync or async inside it.

Comment: @Couteau, turn it into an IIFE: `let x = await (async function() {return "hello"})();`. Works for me.

Comment: We have no idea what `models.usersModel.findOneInvitationByToken` does, but the Promise part is fine. If you're expecting `findOneInvitationByToken` to return something else, the fix needs to go there.

Comment: There must be something wrong with this ``models.usersModel.findOneInvitationByToken(invitationToken, email)`` then. Try to log error in catch block.

Comment: Also, what does your catch block return? You may be converting an error into a result.

Comment: @SandipNirmal here is the errorlog : handledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: I'd suggest a separate question to go into these unrelated issues or starting a chat session if you need interactive debugging help. Hopefully your question on awaiting an anonymous function is answered.

Comment: @Jacob yes it has been answered thank you all. I dont know how to start a chat session but if you'r not to much bothered i would really appreciate it.

Comment: I thought there'd be an easier way to do it, but maybe we just need to link to a chat room?! https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript

Comment: I found the solution, thank you very much for the interest. I put the solution in my post

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You await *Promises*, which are *returned* from async functions, not the async function itself. Just add a call:

```
let x = await (async function() {return "hello"})();
console.log(x);
// or
console.log(await (async() => 'hello')())
```

Comment: I tried that, my console.log now return a serverResponse Object. I will edit my post

Comment: @Couteau That's why you put your actual *asynchronous* code in the question, not only returning a string from an async function (which shouldn't be done in the first place)

Comment: Getting a `serverResponse` is expected if you're using `fetch`. If you want to download the _content_ of the response, you'll need to call its `.json()` or similar methods and await that as well.

Comment: Using that on Node.js causes: ReferenceError: await is not defined

Comment: @Sososlik maybe for really old versions of Node.js. `await` is supported since `7.6`.  You may also see that in the REPL since your version may not support top-level await.

Comment: @Jacob the issue was because I not declared the current function as "async". The error description is confusing in that case.

Answer (score 5):

You are not calling a function in the second case:

```
let x = await hello();
```

This is how you are accessing it in the first case but in the second case, you are just you are adding await to a function declaration. It is just returning function,  you need to change it to

```
let x = await (async function() {return "hello"})();
console.log(x);
```

Comment: I tried that, my console.log now return a serverResponse Object. I will edit my post